# Having trouble with my XML: using layout_above in Relative Layout

Tags: android, xml

I have an *EditText* that I want to autosize until it hits the top of my button underneath. The button needs to stay at the bottom of the screen so I can't use *android:layout_below*. I want to use ***android:layout_above*** but VS spits the error

> No resource found that matches the given name (at 'layout_above' with value '@id/_buttonSave1').

Here's my layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px">
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/_editTextNoteTitle1"
        android:textSize="30dp"
        android:typeface="sans"
        android:text="Title" />
    <TextView
        android:text="Date"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/_editTextNoteTitle1"
        android:id="@+id/_textViewNoteDate1" />
    <EditText
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/_editTextNoteBody1"
        android:text=""
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/_textViewNoteDate1"
        android:layout_above="@id/_buttonSave1"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:scrollbars="horizontal" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/_buttonSave1"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/update"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: What else is in your `layout` file? I can see you reference a `TextView` `textViewNoteDate1`

Comment: I've updated the original post :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `id` is defined in the `Button` *after* it is referenced in `EditText`.

Instead build your layout by first defining the button, and then defining the `EditText` to be above.

Comment: This is just what I needed. Thank you!!